# Can I "add" an ethernet port to laptop using USB-to-Ethernet Adapter

Tags: networking, ethernet, wired-networking

I have a laptop with one ethernet port and a wifi too. To share an internet connection, I connect my laptop through wifi (typically in hotels), then bridge it to the ethernet port by making the internet through the wifi connection "shared". This way I can connect other devices (typically a Vonage Adapter) to this port. However in some hotels I get only a wired internet connection - which will use up the single ethernet port of my laptop. IN such cases, can I connect the USB-to-Ethernet Adapter to the USB port of my laptop and thereby "add" an ethernet port, which I can connect to the Vonage. Obviously I need to "Share" the internet connection on my main port. Would this work ? Will the laptop consider the TWO ethernet ports ? or will one of them over-ride the other. My laptop is HP DV6t-7300.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simplest answer is yes. Add the USB ethernet adapter to your computer, then set either the onboard, or the USB to be shared, and it will work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will work.
You will get 2 Network Adapters in your OS and will be able to use both simultaneously to do what you need/want to do.